# stack smashing detected with gcc-4.8.4 but not with 4.9.1

Tags: c, linux, gcc, stack

I wrote a program in C (snippet below see comment towards the end) compiling 
with gcc. On execution after a while the program dies, with a message

*** stack smashing detected ***

Valgrind does not report any problems that appear to be related to this.
Using gdb approaching the point of failure stepwise i get:

...
107       return(nread);
(gdb) 
108     }
(gdb) 
*** stack smashing detected ***: /home/micb/bin/fogal terminated

Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0x00007ffff7745cc9 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:56
56      ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.

Program terminated with signal SIGABRT, Aborted.

the error occurs while a function terminates ...
"return(nread)", where nread is a local integer, is the last statement
that is executed and just after the function in the main loop there's a 
printf()+fflush statement that is not any more executed ...

funny thing is: i get this error when i compile with gcc-4.8.4
but if i use exactly the same source and program input on a different
machine that has gcc-4.9.2 the error does NOT happen...

is there any way to deal with this other than by installing
a different C compiler?

cheers,
Michael

code:

```
int fitness(const char* id, t_genotype* genome, t_topology_size* size,
            t_topology* top, double* qme, int n_qme) {

      char topfilename[124];
      char tprfilename[124];
      char enefilename[124];
      char logfilename[124];
      char xvgfilename[124];
      char mdpfilename[124];

      char command[124];
      FILE* fxvg;
      double dummy;
      double potential;
      int nread;
      int i;
      double rmsd, sumsq, e0gmx;
      char fnam[124];
      int ret;
      int maxtimeformdrun = (int)((double)(genome->length)/10.0);

      sprintf(topfilename, "top-%s.top", id);
      sprintf(tprfilename, "top-%s.tpr", id);
      sprintf(logfilename, "top-%s.log", id);
      sprintf(enefilename, "top-%s.edr", id);
      sprintf(xvgfilename, "top-%s.xvg", id);
      sprintf(mdpfilename, "top-%s.mdp", id);

      if(write_mod_top(topfilename,size,top,genome)!=0)
        error_msg("Can not write modified topology file");

      sprintf(command, "gmx grompp -f md0.mdp -c onesis.pdb -p %s -o %s -po %s > err1 2>&1", topfilename, tprfilename, mdpfilename);
      if(system(command)!=0) error_msg("gmx grompp failed");

      sprintf(command, "timeout %d gmx mdrun -rerun c-all.trr -s %s -e %s -g %s > err2 2>&1", 
              maxtimeformdrun, tprfilename,enefilename,logfilename);
      ret=system(command);
      if(ret!=0) {
        if(ret=124) {
          fprintf(stderr,"ERROR \"%s\"\n", command);
          fprintf(stderr,"took more than %d seconds\n", maxtimeformdrun);
          fprintf(stderr,"presumably this got stuck, returning a fitness of 1.0e+12");
          genome->fitness = 1.0e+12;
          return(0);
        } else {
          fprintf(stderr,"was trying %s\n", command);
          error_msg("gmx mdrun failed");
        }
      }

      sprintf(command, "cat eterm | gmx energy -f %s -o %s -xvg none > err3 2>&1 ", enefilename,xvgfilename);
      if(system(command)!=0) error_msg("gmx energy failed");

      if((fxvg=fopen(xvgfilename, "r"))==NULL) error_msg("cannot open xvg file");

      nread=0;
      sumsq=0.0;

      while(fscanf(fxvg,"%lf %lf", &dummy, &potential)==2) {

        if(nread==n_qme) error_msg("number of gmx energies larger than n_qme");
        if(nread==0) e0gmx = potential;
        potential -= e0gmx;
        sumsq+=(qme[nread]-potential)*(qme[nread]-potential);
        nread++;
      }

      fclose(fxvg);

      sprintf(command, "rm -f err1 err2 err3 %s %s %s %s %s %s", 
              topfilename, tprfilename, enefilename, logfilename, xvgfilename, mdpfilename);
      if(system(command)!=0) error_msg("removal of gmx files failed");

      genome->fitness = sqrt(sumsq/(double)nread);

      return(nread); // ERROR happens exactly here once the char string in "id" exceeds a certain length (which is MUCH shorter than the allocated length in the calling main function: "char id[256]"
    }
```

Comment: Without a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it's really hard to say what *might* be wrong, or what *might* be done to fix any possible problem.

Comment: Maybe `-fstack_protector` is default option for `4.8.4` while is not default for `4.9.1`

Comment: thanks for the replies ... compileing with -fstack-protector-all i get the same output

Comment: Am I right in thinking that where you said "Valgrind does not report any problems that appear to be related to this", you meant that Valgrind is reporting some problems, just that you don't think they're causing your issue? It's probably worth fixing those problems as any of them could be causing the stack corruption.

Comment: `command[]` looks like it could possibly not be big enough in some circumstances?

Comment: definitely not big enough - look at the last time you call `system` - you're passing 6 filenames in to it. It'd only take `id` to be more than 6 characters for it to exceed the tiny size you've allocated it.

Comment: Change `char command[124];` to `char command[2000];`, and if the problem goes away, you have a hint of what could be wrong.

Comment: And this is also fishy: `if((fxvg=fopen(xvgfilename, "r"))==NULL) error_msg("cannot open xvg file");`. Imagine what happens if `fopen` returns `NULL`.

Comment: @MichaelWalz: It looks to me as though `error_msg()` could be an `_Noreturn` function.  It reports the error and exits.  It would be good to have confirmation of that.  Were it `perror()` reporting the message, you'd have diagnosed a major (potential) problem.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler right, didn't think of that, but without confirmation we can't be sure, and we've seen such code too often here.

Comment: the code does not compile,  the main reason being the 'home grown' type names are not defined within the posted code..  The posted code is not a complete program.  Amongst other things, there is no `main()` function to call the posted function.

Comment: the posted code contains some 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  I.E. 1.0e+12, 10.0, 124.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, maintain.  Suggest giving those 'magic' numbers meaningful names via `#define` statements and using those meaningful names throughout the code.

Comment: the posted code is missing the needed `#include` statements and the data definitions

Comment: i understand its difficult to debug if there are missing bits, but the program is rather lengthy, and shortening it to the essentials might have left out something crucial ... anyway, Chris' suggestion was correct, the command char string was too short, stupid mistake ... sorry, and thanks for the help!! ... and, yes, error_msg aborts the program ...